# Location of 64 bit Libvirt DLLs (windows) for Java client (on 64bit JVM)

Tags: java, dll, libvirt

I have written a Java client (on 64 bit JVM) that uses libvirt APIs on a remote KVM for KVM management. Since the JVM is 64 bit, the client needs 64 bit libvirt dlls and I could not find them (I found 32 bit libvirt dlls on http://libvirt.org/windows.html).

Could someone point to where I could find 64 bit libvirt dlls?

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the 64 bit dll's from the URL that you pointed us to above. They're bundled in the virt-viewer package and can be extracted manually from there.

Comment: I guess the contents of the URL was updated recently. Thanks for pointing this out.